# AWK script input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

```
#!/bin/bash -f

awk '

BEGIN {
    print "type a number";
}
{
    printf "The square of %d is %d\n", $1, $1*$1;
    #print "The square of ", $1, " is ", $1*$1;
    print "type another number\n";
}
END {
    print "Done"
}'
```

Can anyone explain how this program takes input?
I tried searching on the web but in vain.
Grateful for any explanation given.
Thanks.

Comment: input is CLI. Paste that in terminal, hit Enter: everything you tipe into stdin will be fed to the script when hitting Enter again.

Comment: If you're doing nothing but calling awk in your script, you might as well start it with a `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` (adjust for correct location of awk) shebang line and drop the single quotes; see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Executable-Scripts

Comment: Awk will continue reading input and looping until end-of-file (ctrl-d in bash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program takes input from stdin. So, after making it executable with `chmod +x scriptname`, you can either start it with `./scriptname` and answer to each prompt, or redirect a file's content to stdin. For example, suppose this is `numbers.txt`:

```
4
7
1
```

Then execute the script this way:

```
$ ./scriptname < numbers.txt
type a number
The square of 4 is 16
type another number

The square of 7 is 49
type another number

The square of 1 is 1
type another number

Done
```

---

Why does that awk script read standard input? According to [awk POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), section STDIN:

> The standard input shall be used only if no file operands are specified, or if a file operand is '-', or if a progfile option-argument is '-';

Notice that awk was provided no file operand, so stdin is used.

Comment: Why does the program takes input from stdin and how is the program reading it? This might seem like a weird question but i want to understand the workings of the code.

Comment: @FNF I've added the _why_. _How_ is a deeper and totally different question that would be out of place in the answer. I refer you to [How to signal the end of stdin input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16333) and [How does a program detect the end of stdin input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/266637), they may be illuminating.